# Classes and members access

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Hi I need some help on how to define my classes. I know that the code below is not legal. How should i define my classes so I can have a getter for flag in class Values that can access class Person's members?

```
public class Foo
{
    public Dictionary<Person, Values> _elem { get; set; } 
}



private class Values
 {
     //...
    public bool flag { get { return _elem.Person.flag; } }
 }
```

Comment: Neither the code makes sense nor I can understand what you're trying to achieve. Can you explain more clearer?

Comment: Can you explain what you're hoping to achieve? You can't do what you're asking. Even if you made `_elem` static, you still couldn't do what your other code is doing `_elem.Person`...

Comment: You cannot access the Dictionary like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to access the `flag` member of `Person` in the `Values` class you need access to an instance of `Person` inside `Values`, also you cannot mark the `Values` class as `private`

```
public class Values
 {
     private Person _person;
     //...
    public bool flag { get { return _person.flag; } }
 }
```